# Finding $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{f(\alpha x)-f(\beta x)}{x}dx$ given $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, limits

Problem:

[image]

Solution:

> $\bf 45. \; (a)\,$ The substitution $u=\alpha x$, $\mathrm{d}u=\alpha\,\mathrm{d}x$ gives $$\int_{\varepsilon}^N\frac{f(\alpha x)}{x}\mathrm{d}x=\int_{\alpha\varepsilon}^{\alpha N}\frac{f(u)}{u}\mathrm{d}u.$$ Similarly, the substitution $u=\beta x$, $\mathrm{d}u=\beta\,\mathrm{d}x$ gives $$\int_{\varepsilon}^N\frac{f(\beta x)}{x}\mathrm{d}x=\int_{\beta\varepsilon}^{\beta N}\frac{f(u)}{u}\mathrm{d}u.$$ So $$\begin{align}\int_{\varepsilon}^N\frac{f(\alpha x)-f(\beta x)}{x}\mathrm{d}x&=\int_{\alpha\varepsilon}^{\alpha N}\frac{f(u)}{u}\mathrm{d}u-\int_{\beta\varepsilon}^{\beta N}\frac{f(u)}{u}\mathrm{d}u\\&=\int_{\alpha\varepsilon}^{\beta\varepsilon}\frac{f(u)}{u}\mathrm{d}u-\int_{\alpha N}^{\beta N}\frac{f(u)}{u}\mathrm{d}u.\end{align}$$ As $\varepsilon\to0$ and $N\to\infty$, this approaches $$\int_{\alpha\varepsilon}^{\beta\varepsilon}\frac{A}{u}\mathrm{d}u-\int_{\alpha N}^{\beta N}\frac{B}{u}\mathrm{d}u=(A-B)\log\frac{\beta}{\alpha}.$$ $\bf (b)\,$ In this case the same substitutions give $$\int_{\varepsilon}^\infty\frac{f(\alpha x)}{x}\mathrm{d}x=\int_{\alpha\varepsilon}^\infty\frac{f(u)}{u}\mathrm{d}u,\qquad\int_{\varepsilon}^\infty\frac{f(\beta x)}{x}\mathrm{d}x=\int_{\beta\varepsilon}^\infty\frac{f(u)}{u}\mathrm{d}u,$$ so $$\int_{\varepsilon}^\infty\frac{f(\alpha x)-f(\beta x)}{x}\mathrm{d}x=\int_{\alpha e}^{\beta\varepsilon}\frac{f(u)}{u}\mathrm{d}u\to A\log\frac{\beta}{\alpha}.$$

I have two questions regarding this solution.

**First,** how is the substitution $u=\alpha x, du=\alpha dx$ guaranteed to be valid? From my knowledge, the change of variables theorem for integrals work when the function $f(u)/u$ is continuous. This is the version I'm referring to, and all other change of variables theorems share this assumption. So I'm curious how the substitution is valid without the fact that the integrand is continuous.

> **THEOREM 6.4.6.** *(Change of Variables Theorem) Suppose that there exists a differentiable function $g:[c,d]\to[a,b]$ such that $g'\in R[c,d]$. Also, suppose that a function $f:[a,b]\to\mathfrak{R}$ is continuous with $a=g(c)$ and $b=g(d)$. Then $$\int_c^d(f\circ g)(x)g'(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x.$$*

**Finally,** I don't follow the final lines in the solution of (a) and (b).

How do $\int_{\alpha \epsilon}^{\beta \epsilon} \frac{f(u)}{u}du$ and $\int_{\alpha N}^{\beta N} \frac{f(u)}{u}du$ turn into $\int_{\alpha \epsilon}^{\beta \epsilon} \frac{A}{u}du$ and $\int_{\alpha N}^{\beta N} \frac{B}{u}du$ as $\epsilon \to 0$ and $N \to \infty$? I can't give a rigorous argument that this must be the case.

I would immensely appreciate it if anyone could provide me with a rigorous argument to these questions.

Answer (score 2):

The functions with which you are composing are $g(x)=\alpha x$ and $g(x)=\beta x$, and these are both differentiable. Check the proof of the theorem you cite to see where it uses the fact that $f$ needs to be continuous.

For the latter part of the question, since $\alpha,\beta\gt0$, as $\epsilon\to0$, $f(x)\to A$ for $x\in\left[\alpha\epsilon,\beta\epsilon\right]$. Likewise, as $N\to\infty$, $f(x)\to B$ for $x\in\left[\alpha N,\beta N\right]$.

---

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{f(\alpha x)-f(\beta x)}{x}\mathrm{d}x
&=\lim_{\substack{N\to\infty\\\varepsilon\to0}}\int_\varepsilon^N\frac{f(\alpha x)-f(\beta x)}{x}\mathrm{d}x\tag{1}\\
&=\lim_{\substack{N\to\infty\\\varepsilon\to0}}\left[\int_\varepsilon^N\frac{f(\alpha x)}{x}\mathrm{d}x-\int_\varepsilon^N\frac{f(\beta x)}{x}\mathrm{d}x\right]\tag{2}\\
&=\lim_{\substack{N\to\infty\\\varepsilon\to0}}\left[\int_{\alpha\varepsilon}^{\alpha N}\frac{f(x)}{x}\mathrm{d}x-\int_{\beta\varepsilon}^{\beta N}\frac{f(x)}{x}\mathrm{d}x\right]\tag{3}\\
&=\lim_{\substack{N\to\infty\\\varepsilon\to0}}\left[\int_{\alpha\varepsilon}^{\beta\epsilon}\frac{f(x)}{x}\mathrm{d}x-\int_{\alpha N}^{\beta N}\frac{f(x)}{x}\mathrm{d}x\right]\tag{4}\\
&=\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\int_{\alpha\varepsilon}^{\beta\epsilon}\frac{f(x)}{x}\mathrm{d}x-\lim_{N\to\infty}\int_{\alpha N}^{\beta N}\frac{f(x)}{x}\mathrm{d}x\tag{5}\\[6pt]
&=\log\left(\frac\beta\alpha\right)\lim_{x\to0}f(x)-\log\left(\frac\beta\alpha\right)\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)\tag{6}\\[6pt]
&=\log\left(\frac\beta\alpha\right)\left[\lim_{x\to0}f(x)-\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)\right]\tag{7}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: definition of improper integral
$(2)$: linearity of integration
$(3)$: substitute $x\mapsto x/\alpha$ in the left integral and $x\mapsto x/\beta$ in the right
$(4)$: cancel the integrals over $[\beta\epsilon,\alpha N]$
$(5)$: left integral does not depend on $N$; right integral does not depend on $\varepsilon$
$(6)$: as $\varepsilon\to0$, $f(x)\to\lim\limits_{x\to0}f(x)$ on $[\alpha\varepsilon,\beta\varepsilon]$
$\phantom{(6)\text{:}}$ as $N\to\infty$, $f(x)\to\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ on $[\alpha N,\beta N]$
$(7)$: distribute

Comment: Firstly, from the theorem that I cite, $f$ would be $f(u)/u$ in the problem, and $f(u)/u$ is only assumed to be integrable and not continuous in this problem, so I don't see how I can directly apply this theorem. Secondly, could you provide a more rigorous argument as to how the limit on the outside of the integral can be interchanged with the integral sign? I see that it's obvious from your statement, but I haven't been able to show this part rigorously...

Comment: Right; the $\boldsymbol{f}(u)$ in the theorem is $\frac{f(u)}{u}$ in your example. However, **Theorem 6.4.6** assumes that that $\boldsymbol{f}(u)=\frac{f(u)}{u}$ is continuous: $$f:[a,b]\to\mathfrak{R}\textit{ is continuous}$$ *This* is why I was suggesting you check where in the proof continuity is used, since you only have integrability given in the problem whereas continuity is required by the theorem.

Comment: Sorry, it might seem too obvious to you, but I was looking for a proof on showing the step (6). That is, how $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_{\alpha \epsilong}^{\beta \epsilon} f(x)/x dx= log(\beta/\alpha) \lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$. And I think the substitution is guaranteed by the theorem that $\int_{ca}^{cb} f(t)dt =c \int_a^b f(ct) dt$, which I found from another problem.

Comment: The substitution is guaranteed by the theorem, just assuming that $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ is integrable, and $\lim\limits_{x\to0}f(x)$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ exist. Which part of the explanation of step $(6)$ is not clear?

Comment: Do you mean it is guaranteed by Thm 6.4.6? How is it when $f(x)/x$ may only be integrable and not continuous? About step (6), it's hard to explain but I don't see how you can plug that limit inside and separate $\int_{\alpha \epsilon}^{\beta \epsilon} 1/x dx$ and $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$.

Comment: No. Unfortunately, Theorem 6.4.6 needs $f$ to be continuous. The only reason seems to be so that $f$ has an antiderivative and a limit at $0$. However, the theorem is true under more general conditions. As far as $(6)$, what is confusing. I thought the explanation I added covered most things.

Comment: Sorry, hard to describe what I'm unclear with. I mean, from your explanation in (6), shouldn't it also be that as $\epsilon \to 0$, also $x \to 0$, so $1/x \to \infty$. How are we able to leave the denominator part as it is, and just change the nominator to the limit value as $\epsilon \to 0$? I was looking for a more thorough proof of this part.

Comment: @takecare: suppose that $\lim\limits_{x\to0}f(x)=L$. Then $f(x)=L+\delta(x)$ where $\delta(x)\to0$ as $x\to0$. Then $$\begin{align}\left|\,\int_{\alpha\varepsilon}^{\beta\epsilon}\frac{f(x)}{x} \mathrm{d}x - L\log\left(\frac\beta\alpha\right)\,\right| &\le \max_{[\beta\epsilon,\alpha\varepsilon]}|\delta| \int_{\alpha\varepsilon}^{\beta\epsilon}\frac1x\mathrm{d}x\\ &=\max_{[\beta\epsilon,\alpha\varepsilon]}|\delta| \log\left(\frac\beta\alpha\right) \end{align}$$ We can make the right side as small as we want by choosing $\varepsilon$ small enough.