# Chapter 19 Problem 46b) Spivak's Calculus: $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{f(\alpha x)-f(\beta x)}{x}dx=A\log(\frac{\beta}{\alpha})$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, solution-verification

In Chapter 19 of Spivak's *Calculus*, Problem 46b asks the reader the following question:

> Suppose that $\displaystyle \int_a^{\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}dx$ converges for all $a \gt 0$ and that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0}f(x)=A$. Prove that \begin{align}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{f(\alpha x)-f(\beta x)}{x}dx=A\log(\frac{\beta}{\alpha})\end{align}

Using some general integral manipulations /substitutions, I came up with the following expression:
$$\int_{\alpha \varepsilon}^{\beta\varepsilon}\frac{f(u)}{u}du-\int_{\alpha N}^{\beta N}\frac{f(u)}{u}du$$

I can see that $\int_{\alpha \varepsilon}^{\beta\varepsilon}\frac{f(u)}{u}du \to A\log(\frac{\beta}{\alpha})$ as $\varepsilon \to 0^+$...but I am having difficulties understanding why $\int_{\alpha N}^{\beta N}\frac{f(u)}{u}du \to 0$ as $N \to \infty$ (at least, I assume that is what I need to show). Any suggestions would be appreciated!

---

Steps:

\begin{align} \int_{\varepsilon}^{N}\frac{f(\alpha x)-f(\beta x)}{x}dx&=\int_{\varepsilon}^N\frac{f(\alpha x)}{x}dx-\int_{\varepsilon}^N\frac{f(\beta x)}{x}\\&=\int_{\alpha \varepsilon}^{\alpha N}\frac{f(u)}{u}du-\int_{\beta \varepsilon}^{\beta N}\frac{f(u)}{u}du \\ 
\end{align}

Drawing a picture, for example, with $\alpha \varepsilon \lt \beta \varepsilon \lt \alpha N \lt \beta N$ should help visualize why this next step is true:

$$=\int_{\alpha\varepsilon}^{\beta \varepsilon}\frac{f(u)}{u}du-\int_{\alpha N}^{\beta N}\frac{f(u)}{u}du$$

Comment: In your integral $N$ should go to infinity, consider $\int_{a}^{\alpha N} \frac{f(x)}{x} dx + \int_{\alpha N}^{\beta N}\frac{f(x)}{x} dx =\int_{a}^{\beta N} \frac{f(x)}{x} dx $

Comment: @Robearz I am not quite sure I understand the point you are trying to make. Could you please clarify?

Comment: Consider what happens to each term in the identity I posted as $N$ approaches infinity.

Comment: @Robearz it seems like you are trying to say that $\lim_{N\to  \infty}\int_{a}^{\alpha N}\frac{f(x)}{x}dx -\int_{a}^{\beta N}\frac{f(x)}{x}dx=0$...but I am not sure I agree with that. I feel like I would need to know the behavior of $f$ as it approaches infinity in order to conclude this. I'll have to think  about it. Thank you  for the comments.

Comment: $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are just constants presumably greater than $0$ so they both should approach $\int_a^{\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}dx$, which should be a limit defined over real number upper bounds, which implies convergence for a sequence of upper bounds which is weaker.

Comment: @Robearz In my attempt to find a counter example, I now understand your point. I wanted to let $f(x)=x^2$. Then your claim would amount to saying that $\lim_{N \to \infty} \int_a^{\alpha N}x dx - \int_{a}^{\beta N}xdx=0$, which is clearly not true...but $x^2$ violates the assumptions. Thank you!

Comment: Because $\int_a^{\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}dx$ is convergent, so by Cauchy crite, for large $N$ and $M>N$, $|\int_N^{M}\frac{f(x)}{x}dx|<\epsilon$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{f(\alpha x)-f(\beta x)}{x}dx$ given $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1444908/finding-int-0-infty-fracf-alpha-x-f-beta-xxdx-given-lim-x-to-0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to summarize Robearz comments (and close out this post):

We need to show that $\displaystyle \lim_{N \to \infty} \int_{\alpha N}^{\beta N}\frac{f(u)}{u}= 0$.

Note that $\displaystyle  \int_{\alpha N}^{\beta N}\frac{f(u)}{u}=\int_a^{\beta N}\frac{f(u)}{u}-\int_a^{\alpha N}\frac{f(u)}{u}$ for an arbitrary $a \in (0,\infty)$.

Given that $\beta N  \to \infty$ and $\alpha N \to \infty$ as $N \to \infty$, we have by assumption that:

$\displaystyle \lim_{N\to \infty}\int_a^{\beta N}\frac{f(u)}{u}=L_a$  and $\displaystyle \lim_{N\to \infty}\int_a^{\alpha N}\frac{f(u)}{u}=L_a$. Therefore, we have that:

\begin{align}\lim_{N\to \infty} \int_{\alpha N}^{\beta N}\frac{f(u)}{u}&=\lim_{N\to \infty}\int_a^{\beta N}\frac{f(u)}{u}-\int_a^{\alpha N}\frac{f(u)}{u}\\&=\lim_{N\to \infty}\int_a^{\beta N}\frac{f(u)}{u}-\lim_{N\to \infty}\int_a^{\alpha N}\frac{f(u)}{u}\\&=L_a-L_a=0 \end{align}